# Fancybox infinite loop - Cannot read property 'href' of undefined

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to add a lightbox via fancybox behavior to my site, but inspecting with a JS profiler after clicking on the image to be lightboxed with FF or Chrome, I get into an infinite loop with this error:

`Cannot read property 'href' of undefined`

Images are however loaded, although with bugs when closing or with crashing the browser sometimes, but the infinite number of these calls and recreating the images in the HTML source code causes this to happen.

This is my HTML with images:

```
<div class="below_shadow" style="top: 0px;">
    <a class="portfolio_link" href="http://mywebsite.com/images/DSC_0258-794x1024.jpg">
    <img class="frame" alt="" src="http://mywebsite.com/images/DSC_0258-794x1024.jpg&amp;h=131&amp;w=180&amp;zc=1" style="top: 0px;">
    </a>
    <span style="display: none;" class="portfolio4_hover">
        <a style="top: 0px; " class="portfolio_image" href="javascript:;">
            <img alt="" src="http://mywebsite.com/images/icon_zoom.png">
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

And this is my call in the JS section:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.below_shadow a.portfolio_link').fancybox({ 
    padding: 0,
    overlayColor: '#000', 
    transitionIn: 'elastic',
    transitionOut: 'elastic', 
    overlayOpacity: .8,
    showNavArrows: true
});
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you have some other code you haven't shared yet that is causing this problem. Try posting a basic demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'm not familiar with fancybox, but it appears to me that something in the fancybox code base is attempting to access the href property of the image link that you have defined with the portfolio_link.  However, that image does not exist on the server, and returns a 404.

Start by making sure the image you are referencing is actually available at the location you are referencing and then touch base.

Answer (score 0):

The Fancybox plugin has a bug with synchronization or calling image resources. When image is clicked, the transparent div loads the big image + the title. Under some unknown circumstances the title is not always loaded and this causes a bug in the system.

Even if your anchors and images do have the "title" attribute, there seems to be some fancybox bug leading to this inner loop and leak by not passing the title argument properly.

Comment: pretty much, but I don't know whether it's a problem in the fancybox or the jQuery calls because this is where the inner loop starts (some jquery call from the fancybox lib)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error - the infinite loop is called when this code is evaluated:

```
jQuery(this).find('.portfolio4_hover').show();
```

Honestly - dunno why, but this is the case. If I comment this line (and it's hide line below), everything works correctly.